# ZSH: Command not found - after update macOS to 10.15.1

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, zsh

Yesterday I was using all my installed packages without any problem such as `mysql`, `composer`, `php`, `brew` and co...

However, today I started my MacBook and typed `mysql` and I got: `zsh: command not found: mysql`. Not even `brew` is working anymore and I don't know why.. this is my `.zshrc` config file and I don't know why it isn't working.

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: And did you verify, whether the directory containing `mysql` is represented in this PATH?

Answer (score 2):

Yuck, how did that happen? Try this:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Whether this works is going to depend on where you have been installing user executables. If you're using homebrew, I would expect it to be `/usr/local/bin` but perhaps it is something different in your case? You might want to try putting `/usr/local/bin` first so things installed by homebrew get picked up before the defaults in `/usr/bin` and `/bin` (this is what I do, and I'm still alive to talk about it...)

You could also change your default shell back to Bash:

```
brew install bash
echo '/usr/local/bin/bash' >> /etc/shells
chsh
```

You might need to use `sudo` on line 2.